# How to delete record 1 and record 2 in different table using relationship in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Here we go in my situation I have videos and video_tags table and it has a relationship one to many because in a video has many tags. I'm trying to achieve to delete record1 and record2 storing in different table using relationship in one query only then the records will be deleted from table1 and table2. I think it is possible in laravel please i need help.

**Model:**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Video extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'videos';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\VideoTag');
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function postDeleteVideo(Request $request, $id){
        $tag = Video::find($id)->tags->delete();// <-- problem here
        return response()->json(array('success'=>true));
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want when a video is deleted the related tags be removed in tags table? By the way, I think you need a many to many relationship between tags and videos and therefore a pivot table. For this you can refer to laravel documentation for many to many relationships

Comment: @Ali Erfani Yes i want the video deleted and the related tags from the other table but by one query only.

Comment: What you need is explained in this video [link](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set CASCADE relationships in your database.

Then...

$video = \Video::find(1);

$video->delete();